# Android 7.1.2 QuickSettings tile not being tinted

Tags: android, settings, android-7.1-nougat

I've been racking my brain for over an hour trying to figure out why my QuickSettings tile is not being tinted based on Tile.STATE_ACTIVE and Tile.STATE_INACTIVE. I use the same icon, which is set in the manifest, but I change the state dynamically in onStartListening. This was working fine on Android 7.1.1.

Has anyone else noticed their QuickSettings tile not being tinted?

Comment: Accidentally stumbled across this post after providing off state drawables with an alpha channel a few months back. @Flar2 Your discovery explains why my tiles with transparency set in the alpha channel now show lighter than the rest of the system tiles, the drawables must be being cached. It's been bugging the life out of me.

Answer (score 2):

Set the icon explicitly for each state and it will get tinted properly.  You must use a different drawable resource for each state or it won't change. Luckily it can be the exact same icon. I just copied ic_powersave_tile and renamed it ic_powersave_tile2.  I discovered this by accident, one of my apps worked on 7.1.2 and one didn't, this was then only difference.

```
private void setCurrentState(int state){
    Tile tile = getQsTile();

    if (tile == null)
        return;

    tile.setState(state);
    switch (state){
        case Tile.STATE_ACTIVE:
            tile.setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.drawable.ic_powersave_tile));
            break;

        case Tile.STATE_INACTIVE:
            tile.setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.drawable.ic_powersave_tile2));
            break;

        case Tile.STATE_UNAVAILABLE:
            tile.setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.drawable.ic_powersave_tile));
            break;

    }

    tile.updateTile();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, while everything was working fine till 7.1.1.
It looks like this is happening starting Android 7.1.2.
I observed the same behavior while this release was in beta. I had to roll back to 7.1.1 to properly test my app, and I was sure such issue was going to be fixed in the final 7.1.2 release. But it hasn't.
The same thing can be reproduced also with some frameworks tiles, such as **Show layout bounds** and **Profile GPU rendering**: those tiles won't reflect the on/off state. I have no idea how something so obvious has been ignored in the 7.1.2 final release. So far the only temporary solution I have in mind is to provide drawables for the off state, adding more resources to the final apk. It is not a solution, but at least it could help to better understand the on/off state.

Comment: @Flyview I did: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=326265